# Turning a data frame column to an array of dictionaries in YAML

Tags: r, yaml

I'm trying to generate the following YAML structure from tabular data:

```yaml
- name: Josiah Carberry
  roles: 
    - investigation: lead 
    - data curation: supporting
```

I'm struggling with the structure of the `roles` key. It's basically an array of dictionaries which would translate to a list of data frames in R.

My issue is that I can't figure out how to store such lists of data frames in a way that will produce the same output as in the example above.

Here's my attempt:

```r
library(tibble)

tibble(
  id = paste0("id", 1:2),
  roles = list(
    list(tibble(writing = "lead"), tibble(supervision = "supporting")),
    list(tibble(writing = "equal"))
  )
) |> 
  jsonlite::toJSON() |> 
  jsonlite::parse_json() |> 
  yaml::as.yaml(indent.mapping.sequence = TRUE) |> 
  cat()
```

Which produces:

```yaml
- id: id1
  roles:
    - - writing: lead
    - - supervision: supporting
- id: id2
  roles:
    - - writing: equal
```

As you can see there's one extra dash before each role because of the outer list I use to store the data frames.

Any idea how I could get the following?

```yaml
- id: id1
  roles:
    - writing: lead
    - supervision: supporting
- id: id2
  roles:
    - writing: equal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1: regex

I don't know a way for `yaml::as.yaml` to do it correctly the first time, but you can always do a simple `gsub` to change all `- -` manually:

```r
tibble(
  id = paste0("id", 1:2),
  roles = list(
    list(tibble(writing = "lead"), tibble(supervision = "supporting")),
    list(tibble(writing = "equal"))
  )
) |> 
  jsonlite::toJSON() |> 
  jsonlite::parse_json() |> 
  yaml::as.yaml(indent.mapping.sequence = TRUE) |>
  gsub("- - ", "- ", x = _) |>
  cat()
# - id: id1
#   roles:
#     - writing: lead
#     - supervision: supporting
# - id: id2
#   roles:
#     - writing: equal
```

If there's a risk you could have a legitimate `- -` embedded within one of your items, you can make the `gsub` a bit more specific:

```r
  gsub("((^|\n) *)- - ", "\\1- ", x = _)
```

where

- `(^|\n)` matches either the string beginninf (`^`) or the embedded newline; this is necessary because `as.yaml` returns a single string with `\n` embedded within it, so we cannot rely on `^` to catch them all; we could always use `strsplit(_, "\n")[[1]]` to split it then `gsub` then recombine, but that seems unnecessary given we can do it in one step
- `((^|\n) *)` finds the above plus zero or more spaces; I think `" "` is safe here instead of `"\\s"`, since I believe `as.yaml` is always going to put out spaces there; because this is wrapped in parens, it will be available as a pattern group for later recall
- `"\\1- "` replaces everything in the pattern (including the `- -`) with the parenthesized pattern group (previous bullet) and a single hyphen-space.

## Option 2: convert from `tibble` to `list`:

Up front, this fixes the `- -` problem with the above, though it converts inline dictionaries with nested. Formally, they resolve to the same underlying structure, so if you're okay with the added verbosity then perhaps this is better:

```r
tibble(
  id = paste0("id", 1:2),
  roles = list(
    list(tibble(writing = "lead"), tibble(supervision = "supporting")),
    list(tibble(writing = "equal"))
  )
) |> 
  transform(roles = rapply(roles, unlist, how = "list")) |>
  jsonlite::toJSON() |> 
  jsonlite::parse_json() |> 
  yaml::as.yaml(indent.mapping.sequence = TRUE) |> 
  cat()
# - id: id1
#   roles:
#     - writing:
#         - lead
#     - supervision:
#         - supporting
# - id: id2
#   roles:
#     - writing:
#         - equal
```

This looks slightly different than your expected, though they are still valid yaml dictionaries. The *effective* result is confirmed with:

```r
out1 <- tibble(
  id = paste0("id", 1:2),
  roles = list(
    list(tibble(writing = "lead"), tibble(supervision = "supporting")),
    list(tibble(writing = "equal"))
  )
) |> 
  jsonlite::toJSON() |> 
  jsonlite::parse_json() |> 
  yaml::as.yaml(indent.mapping.sequence = TRUE) |>
  gsub("- - ", "- ", x = _)
out2 <- tibble(
  id = paste0("id", 1:2),
  roles = list(
    list(tibble(writing = "lead"), tibble(supervision = "supporting")),
    list(tibble(writing = "equal"))
  )
) |> 
  transform(roles = rapply(roles, unlist, how = "list")) |>
  jsonlite::toJSON() |> 
  jsonlite::parse_json() |> 
  yaml::as.yaml(indent.mapping.sequence = TRUE)

out1
# [1] "- id: id1\n  roles:\n    - writing: lead\n    - supervision: supporting\n- id: id2\n  roles:\n    - writing: equal\n"
out2
# [1] "- id: id1\n  roles:\n    - writing:\n        - lead\n    - supervision:\n        - supporting\n- id: id2\n  roles:\n    - writing:\n        - equal\n"
identical(yaml::read_yaml(text = out1), yaml::read_yaml(text = out2))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I could always use regexes to tweak the output but I've to admit I'm not a big fan of using regexes here. This is for a package I'm developing and I find the solution somewhat fragile. I'll see if someone else come up with another solution, otherwise I'll accept your answer.

Comment: See my edit for another option using `rapply` to un-`tibble` them. I'm not sure if the underlying use of `tibble(.)` is _yours_ or inherited from elsewhere. Ultimately, if internally `roles` is defined as `list(list(writing = "lead"), list(supervision = "supporting"))` instead of your `tibble`-based, it works without the `rapply`, in case that helps. @arangaca

Comment: I'll have to check if that remains valid in my use case. The YAML structure comes from [Quarto](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/front-matter.html#roles) (see the last code chunk of the "Author Roles" section). My [package](https://arnaudgallou.github.io/plume/index.html) aims at injecting metadata to the YAML header of Quarto files so I'm dependent on their format. This is a new feature I wanted to add to support contribution degrees. It's not an essential feature though so I might just skip it.